# Implementing angular 2 set title tag

Tags: angular

I'm trying to adapt this example (https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title) to my implementation, which has significantly more pieces. I don't yet fully understand what all the angular 2 pieces are and how they fit together.

Their main.ts:

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Mine:

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
} 

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

OK so far.

Their app.module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        Title
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Mine:

```js
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER  } from '@angular/core';

import { serviceConfigFactory, AppConfig } from './app.config';
... about 50 other imports
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http, siteService:SiteService) {
    return new LocalizationLoader(http,siteService);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    BaseLoginComponent,
    ClientSwitchComponent,
    SwitchClientComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JWBootstrapSwitchModule,
    DatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    TypeaheadModule.forRoot(),
    MomentModule,
    SharedModule,
    AuthModule,
    CompanyModule,
    RequestTimeOffModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [Http, SiteService]
        }
    }),
    StoreModule.provideStore({ appState: appStateReducer }),
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: AppConfig, useFactory: serviceConfigFactory },
    SiteService,
    AppContext,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: AppContextLoader, deps: [AppContext], multi: true },
    EmployeeService,
    LeavesService,
    ServiceManager,
    EncryptionService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here's where I run into trouble:

Their app.component.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template:
  `<p>
    Select a title to set on the current HTML document:
  </p>

  <ul>
    <li><a (click)="setTitle( 'Good morning!' )">Good morning</a>.</li>
    <li><a (click)="setTitle( 'Good afternoon!' )">Good afternoon</a>.</li>
    <li><a (click)="setTitle( 'Good evening!' )">Good evening</a>.</li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
  }
}
```

Mine:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AppContext } from './services/app.context';
import {AuthService} from './services/auth/auth.service';
import { CompanyRoutes } from './features/company/company.routes';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})


export class AppComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router, public auth: AuthService, public appContext: AppContext, translate: TranslateService, private companyRoutes: CompanyRoutes, private titleService: Title) {
        if (appContext.siteConfig.clientCode) {
            this.companyRoutes.resetCompanyRoutes(appContext.siteConfig.clientCode);
        }
    }

    public setTitle(newTitle: string) {
        this.titleService.setTitle(newTitle);
    }
}
```

Now, I don't want it to perform setTitle on app.component .ts; I want to do it as soon as it hits the first page (and then every subsequent page, so this is what I'm expecting to do:

My login.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SiteService } from '../../../services/site.service';
import { AppContext } from '../../../services/app.context';
import { LoginConfig, AppState } from '../../../models/site/site.config';
import {AuthService} from '../../../services/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class BaseLoginComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {

        this.setTitle("!");
    }
}
```

login.component.ts does not recognize `this.setTitle()` or `setTitle();`

I don't really understand the purpose of these `app.component` and `app.module` fields are, and how they connect together, so I'm not sure how to expose `setTitle` to my pages.

Comment: You left   setTitle(newTitle: string) {
        this.titleService.setTitle(newTitle);
    } in app.component.ts. You have to put it in BaseLoginComponent. And don't forget to move the import of TitleService

Comment: Yeah, so that's what I was wondering. I gotta put it on **every page**??

Comment: I am not sure to understand you. You are asking if you should put setTitle on every page so your app has consistantly the same title?

Comment: Ah. Sorry. The content for each page is wrapped in a common _IndexLayout.html. So each page needs tell the title tag what its name is. (This is a parameter that would normally be handled through the routing.)

Comment: When you call this.doSomething(), doSomething is a method that should be defined in the same class, as 'this' refers to the  class. If you need a method in a service you inject it via the constructor and you can call like this someService.doSomething().

Comment: Ah of course. It should be a service, so it's available everywhere. I'm overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the relevant parts from my project to update title and meta tags. (Angular 2/4)**

---

**app-routing.module.ts:**

> **Routes:**

```
... const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'path1', loadChildren: './path1#path1Module',
        data: {
            title: '...',
            description: '...',
            keywords: '...'
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'path2', loadChildren: './path2#path2Module',
        data: {
            title: '...',
            description: '...',
            keywords: '...'
        }
    } ...
```

**app.component.ts (or your bootstrap component):**

> imports:

```
// imports
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { Title,Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

> constructor:

```
    // constructor:
        constructor(private router: Router,
                    private route: ActivatedRoute,
                    private titleService: Title, private meta: Meta) {}
```

> **ngOnInit() method:**

```
ngOnInit() {

        this.router.events
            .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .map(() => this.route)
            .map((route) => {
                while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
                return route;
            })
            .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
            .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
            .subscribe((event) => {
                this.updateDescription(event['description'], event['keywords'], event['title']);
            });

    }
```

> **method that updates title and meta tags -> called from ngOnInit():**

```
updateDescription(desc: string, keywords: string, title: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle(title);
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: desc })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: keywords })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:title', content: title })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:description', content: desc })
}
```

**Hope it helps.**